# Razor Wrap Attributes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, razor, blazor

Which Visual Studio Configuration is needed to wrap attributes in Razor/Blazor components?

Instead of

```
<SampleComponent Message="Welcome to Blazor" IsVisible="true" Count="42" Color="green" Options="@(new List<string> { "Option A", "Option B", "Option C" })" />
```

it should look like the following example which wraps Attributes if the line is too long.

```
  <SampleComponent
      Message="Welcome to Blazor" IsVisible="true" Count="42"
      Color="green" Options="@(new List<string> { "Option A", "Option B", "Option C" })" />
```

Comment: There is no error message. It just does not format it. Even if i format manually or use code cleanup.

Comment: OK, you are asking about (re)formatting the code. That wasn't clear to me.